# Blender doesn't display texture properly but meshlab does

Tags: texturing, uv

I have an obj along with a texture file but the texture is not loading properly on blender.
[image: this is how the texture looks on blender]

But when I load the same obj into meshlab it loads it perfectly
[image: correctly loaded on meshlab]

Here's the obj link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FfU37yN3ei2llcKSAKS2mwQBtWpVFPtX/view?usp=sharing
and texture link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gW6NOAwOS-qXw97ar7iOrMlClOK-Kyds/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Blender results in that state, because there is not *UVmap* delivered with obj.

On other hand, importing your OBJ to Meshlab doesn't use your texture at all. I would say it uses *Vertex Color* info ... the weird thing is imported OBJ to Blender doesn't have any Vertex Color either, even when I export obj from meshlab with vertex color ... hm.

---

Before than someone smarter will answer this "mystery" ... You have two options - open your OBJ file in *Meshlab* and *Export as* PLY format. There I have no issue to use the **Vertex Color**.

[image]

If you want to use **Image Texture**, you would have to create UV map in Meshlab first and than transfer Vertex Color to Texture. For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51582851/10148444 ... this worked for me too.